# How to catch exception when Laravel cannot connect to Redis?

Tags: laravel, redis

Iam using Redis as cache in Laravel.

But I cannot catch Exception when laravel cannot connect to Redis (redis stopped, ...). I want catch this exception to reponse to client by JSON.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Are you know about `try` & `catch` and how  it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `render()` function of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class as:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof SomeRedisException) {
        return response()->json('Redis Error',500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler)

Comment: Thanks a ton ! It work ! $exception is instance of class ConnectionException ! (y)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Iam newbie on Stack Overflow. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

In case of Redis connection error - the `RedisException` will be thrown by `phpredis` extension.

Somewhere in your Controller or Middleware:

```php
try {
    // Call Laravel Cache facade when Redis connection is failing
    // This will throw exception
    Cache::get('cache_key');
} catch (RedisException $exception) {
    // In case Redis error - do custom response
    Log::error('Redis error', [
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'trace' => $exception->getTrace()
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'your error message to client'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please note that this will not work for API routes due to `Throttle` middleware which is trying to connect to Redis (in order to get cached requests amount) before others middleware\controllers.

Comment: Also does not work if you are using redis for sessions because `StartSession` middleware is doing the same.